# not loading button properly

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Hi can anyone help me please I'm having a hard time making this work and been trying so many ways to make this work but everytime I run this code it only shows the beginner1Check even if I turn the boolean to true. can anyone help me please?

here are my codes

**.java**

```
public void initialize(){

    SharedPreferences beginner1Prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean beginner1_pref = beginner1Prefs.getBoolean("Beginner1", false);

    if (beginner1_pref == false){
        beginner1Check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner1Check);
        beginner1Check.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
    } else if (beginner1_pref == true){
        beginner1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner1);
        beginner1.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
    }

    btnLogo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogo);
    beginner2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner2);
    beginner3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner3);
    beginner4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner4);
    beginner5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner5);
    beginner6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner6);
    beginner7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner7);
    beginner8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner8);
    beginner9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner9);


    btnLogo.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
    beginner2.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
    beginner3.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
    beginner4.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
    beginner5.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
    beginner6.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
    beginner7.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
    beginner8.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
    beginner9.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);

}
```

**xml > prefs.xml**

```
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:title="Beginner1"
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:key="Beginner1"
    android:summary="Beginner1" />
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?? Give more details.

Comment: I'm trying to load button1 if beginner1_pref = true and hide button2 then on beginner1_pref = false show button2 then hide button1

Comment: Give your `Activity` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't made the second `Button` invisible. You have just initialized the first `Button` but your second `Button` obviously exists in your layout. It won't hide unless you explicitly hide it. Modify your code like this:

```
if (beginner1_pref == false){
        beginner1Check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner1Check);
        beginner1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner1);
        beginner1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);//You can replace it with VIEW.GONE depending on your needs.
        beginner1Check.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
    } else if (beginner1_pref == true){
        beginner1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner1);
        beginner1Check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBeginner1Check);
        beginner1Check.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        beginner1.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);
    }
```

Comment: @Naddy Please do not tell people they must accept answers. *That is not true at all.*